# Windows 7 ultimate features on or off dialog box is empty

Tags: windows-7

can any body help me, when i try to turn on windows feature like "IIS",i see my windows features on or off dialog box is empty, nothing is there, what i doing, my windows is windows 7 ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

#### Fix for "Windows Features dialog box is empty in Windows 7..." ([*Source*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931712))

1. Click Start, and then type cmd in the Start Search box.
2. In the results area, right-click cmd.exe, and then click Run as administrator. You will be prompted to type the password for an administrator account. Click Continue if you are the administrator or type the administrator password. Then, click Continue.
3. At the command prompt, type Sfc /scannow, and then press ENTER.

*The scan may take some time, so be patient. Windows will repair any corrupted or missing files that it finds. If information from the installation CD is needed to repair the problem, you may be prompted to insert your Windows Vista or Windows 7 CD.*

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/fix-blank-or-empty-list-in-vista-turn-windows-features-on-or-off-optionalfeaturesexe/ ([here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160326165318/https://www.raymond.cc/blog/fix-blank-or-empty-list-in-vista-turn-windows-features-on-or-off-optionalfeaturesexe/) is web archive version of the article if the original version ever gets deleted)

I followed all steps and managed to fix it for me.

There are other advices here: [how to fix empty turn windows features on or off](https://superuser.com/questions/548332/how-to-fix-empty-turn-windows-features-on-or-off)