# how to fix empty turn windows features on or off

Tags: windows-7, control-panel

I am running win 7 home premium, and now I see my windows and features list is always empty, i tried many solutions but nothing did it.
[image]

I tried [this last thing](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/fix-blank-or-empty-list-in-vista-turn-windows-features-on-or-off-optionalfeaturesexe/) but failed to solve as well

Comment: Have you tried booting in secure mode and/or did you turned of some services by yourself?

Comment: can't remember i turned of any services my self, and I didn't boot in secure mode.

Comment: Start the program **msconfig** and have a look at your services. Give the secure mode a try too!!

Comment: which service should be running to make this work?

Comment: Sry this is a to spezific question for my knowlage. i would turn on everything and have a look. It could be a registry error to. You might backup your Registry with **ccleaner** and do a repair with cclearner. ccleaner rarely really repairs your regestry but better give a try then reinstallinh the hole system.

Comment: i did this registry clean but nothing fixed, will try enable services.

Comment: First, run the System File checker to see if you have any corrupted system files.

Click **Start** Type: **CMD**, from the results, right click CMD Click
**Run as Administrator**, At the Command Prompt, type: **sfc/scannow**, and press ENTER

This will check for any integrity violations and fix any corrupted operating system files.

Restart your system

Comment: said: no integrity violations found

Answer (score 2):

If you run into this issue, you can try this option. It should be **run as an administrator.**

- Running `sfc /scannow`, in safe mode is best
- Run `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`
- Install windows update **KB2862966**

Different things have worked for different people and it's most likely connected to what is causing the trouble for that individual. Any number of corrupt files etc could be the issue.

Comment: The /RestoreHealth switch for dism is only available on Window NT 6.2+. The OP specifically tagged his question for Windows 7 and provided a Windows 7 screenshot. dism should not be suggested; SURT is the appropriate tool instead.